# What happens during template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
// 1:
void compare(T, T) {}

int main{
    compare("123", "45");
}
// T is const char *

// 2:
void compare(T *, T *) {}
// T is const char

// 3:
void compare(const T *, const T *) {}
// T is char

// 4:
void compare(const T, const T) {}
// T is const char *
```

1:

My question is according to the pattern of 1,2,3 which I can totally understand
why T becomes how it looks like.Whereas T in the 4'th code is not `char *` which I presumed.

2:

And why the first code and the 4'th code resulting the same type of T.

3:

Can I use a `reference` of `const char *` as parameter in `compare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `compare` gets string literals, whose types are `const char *`;

> 1: My question is according to the pattern of 1,2,3 which I can
>   totally understand why T becomes how it looks like.Whereas T in the
>   4'th code is not char * which I presumed.

In `const T` the const refers to T, which is `const char*`. The const in 
`const char*` refers to char. The two cases of const refer to different things. With `const T x` we can't change x, i.e., the pointer x itself. With `const char* x` we can change the pointer, but not the characters pointed by x.

> 2: And why the first code and the 4'th code resulting the same type of
>   T.

See answer above. The const in `const T` is redundant for the caller. The caller does not care if the implementation will, or will not, change its copy of the pointer. Only the implementation cares about it.

> 3: Can I use a reference of const char * as parameter in compare

Sure, simply write `const T&`, or `const char*const&` (read from right to left: a reference to a constant pointer to a character constant)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is according to the pattern of 1,2,3 which I can totally understand why T becomes how it looks like.Whereas T in the 4'th code is not char * which I presumed.

Because you were misled into recognizing a wrong pattern. This is an example of why "leading const is misleading". Templates aren't like macros, and the placement of the `const` on the left doesn't mean it applies to the `char`. It applies to the whole parameter type, and since the parameter is going to be a pointer (on account of the literals being given as arguments), the synthesized function is going to be something like this:

```
void compare(char const* const, char const* const) {}
```

This is why many C++ programmers (including myself), favor a different placement of of cv-qualifers. Where your options 3 and 4 would have been written like this:

```
void compare(T const *, T const *) {}
// T is char

// 4:
void compare(T const, T const ) {}
// T is const char *
```

It's more consistent, because `const` always applies to what's on the left of it (if there is something, otherwise there's an exception, and a confusing exception). And it also makes it abundantly clear (well, IMO anyway) what is going to be const when the deduction is over.

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't see much readability difference between the two options. Is there some research showing statistical difference between bugs in both placements? (somehow neutralizing the effect of the right hand CV crowd tends to be more proficient on average)

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I don't have any statistics available – but I pretty often see especially beginners not getting the matter right with the more common style. This question is an example for... Searching a little should reveal further examples. I think the more one is experienced, the less it will be a problem; at some point of time, people simply know about.

Comment: @Aconcagua but isn't it possible that this is a simple case of correlation: mostly proficient coders write cv on the right, so you see less bugs of this type for proficient coders. Had it been taught in class to put cv on the right, and proficient preferred the other way around, wouldn't the situation be reversed? I have seen too many cases of bad anecdotal conclusions, to accept statements without a carefully managed experiment. Maybe have a professor teach two classes differently, and compare results

Comment: @MichaelVeksler - Then you reject most style guides? Most of them are based on anecdotal experience (from many programmers usually, but anecdotal nonetheless). Now, I don't know of any statistical analysis that evaluates the error ratio of each coding style, but consistency has been hailed time and time again as serving a diminishing factor in making mistakes. This coding style *is* more consistent with the rules of the base language, which is why I am a proponent of it.

Comment: And as the saying goes, style guides are cultural. None of this is a hill to die on, just a bunch of devs sharing their personal experience and agreeing on something they can all live with.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Maybe that's a bit too short: Even the proficient coders once learnt – let me call it – the 'classic' style (reflects my own history, too...). Why *did* they change? That might be a hint already (but nothting more either). If you did that two classes experiment, one would have to consider, too, how many of each class switch to the respective other style later on, too.

Comment: I agree; Consistency of and lack of surprise are important; that's why we have style guides. Unfortunately c++ is filled with many little inconsistencies, and we should avoid the ones we can easily avoid, like having cv on the right

Answer (score 1):

> Whereas T in the 4'th code is not `char *` which I presumed.

Note that in the 4th code, `const` is qualified on `T` directly. When `T` is deduced as a pointer, then `const T` means `const` pointer, not pointer to `const`. So `T` is deduced as `const char*`, and the argument of the 4th `compare` will be `const char * const`.

Let's suppose that `T` is deduced as `char *`, then `const T` will be `char * const` (i.e. a `const` pointer to non-`const` `char`), which is not the expected argument type obviously.

> Can I use a reference of `const char *` as parameter in `compare`

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, yes you can write something like `void compare(const T&, const T&)` to change it to pass-by-reference, but also note for `compare("123", "45");` `T` will be deduced as array type (for this case the deduction would fail in fact, because `"123"` and `"45"` are not the same array type), array-to-pointer decay won't happen. This might not be what you expected.